# swfobject in Uploadify not working with IE 7 or 8

Tags: swfobject, uploadify

I am using Uploadify and have a pop up which is loaded by jQuery by Ajax. The page on which the popup lives on has an include to swfobject (from Google's Code Api) and the Uploadify button should appear.

This works great on FF and Chrome but IE gives me a javascript error

Unknown runtime error line 4 character 5942

Anyone got any ideas how to fix this problem?

It's possibly to do with the fact that I'm using it from within dynamic content.

I found the following link but there is no definitive answer

[Possible answer](http://www.wooliet.com/2009/07/22/swfobject-ie-and-dynamic-content-a-problem/comment-page-1/#comment-2962)

Comment: At which point are you generating the uploadify content and where? In the popup? Can you go into a bit more detail and show some code? Would it be an option to prepare uploadify in static HTML, and show it on demand?

Comment: I'm calling the uploadify() method on my file input from within the partial content which is loaded in by jquery into my div popup and I think this probably is the issue. It works perfectly on Chrome and FireFox however, IE's complaint is to do with outerHTML and so is something to do with being created dynamically I believe

Calling Uploadify() statically isn't really an option as the popup is one of many on the page but I may have to consider it as a site that doesn't work in IE isn't too good!

Answer (score 4):

Use the unpacked swfobject.js version from the [swfobject download](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/downloads/detail?name=swfobject_2_2.zip).
Go to line 435 in your unpacked file and change

```
el.outerHTML = '<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"' + att + '>' + par + '</object>';
```

to

```
jQuery(el).replaceWith('<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"' + att + '>' + par + '</object>');
```

This will only work if you use jQuery...

Comment: it worked for me, tanks. Worst part is that uploadify used to work well, but after adding other scripts IE refused to work ;)

Answer (score 1):

That link I mentioned in my original post did indeed have the [answer](http://www.wooliet.com/2009/07/22/swfobject-ie-and-dynamic-content-a-problem/comment-page-1/#comment-2962)

I had to download the source swfobject.js file and edit the line mentioned to use $(el).replaceWith and that allows the uploadify() content to load without error.

Answer (score 0):

Replace  if (typeof (movieElement[key]) === "function") to if (typeof (movieElement[key]) === "function" && key.substring(0, 1) <= 'Z') in js file.